# Not able to access parents property on child style trigger in Wpf

Tags: wpf

In my implementation I have a ListView inside a GroupBox. In one scenario the visibility of all the list items in the ListView is set to hidden. In this scenario I want to collapse/hide the entire GroupBox.

In this scenario the collection list used for binding still has all the items in it and we are using datatigger to change their visibility upon some status changes in the items.

Please see the rough example structure below.

```
<GroupBox Header="Pizza" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="206" Width="263">
<ListView Margin="10,10,0,13" Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Tag="test"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Height="100">
    <ListViewItem Content="Coffie" Visibility="Hidden"></ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Tea" Visibility="Hidden"></ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You want to hide you groupbox or your listview, please explain more your question

Comment: groupbox when all the listview items are collapsed

Comment: And What exactly the Problem or error you are getting?